# Scraping google headlines suddenly stop working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have wrote a code for web scraping google news page. It worked fine till today, when it stopped.
It does not give me any error, but It does not scrape anything.

For this code I have watched tutorial from 2018 on youtube and I have used the same `url` and same 'div's.

When I go to 'inspect' on browser, it still has `class="st"` and `class="slp"`

I mean, that means that it worked one year ago till, and it worked yesterday, but It stopped working today

Do you know what can be the problem?
This is the code that worked yesterday:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

term = 'coca cola'

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&source=lnms&tbm=nws'.format(term)

response = requests.get(url)
print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

snippet_text = soup.find_all('div', class_='st')
print(len(snippet_text))

news_date = soup.find_all('div', class_='slp')
print(len(news_date))

for paragraph_text, post_date in zip(snippet_text, news_date):

        paragraph_text = TextBlob(paragraph_text.get_text())
        print(paragraph_text)

        todays_date = date.today()
        time_ago = TextBlob(post_date.get_text()).split('- ')[1]
        print(time_ago)
```

Does google changes HTML code or url?

Comment: I ran it and it's returning results just fine for me. Are you sure you're running the correct script?

Comment: It returns `soup`, but does it return `print(len(snippet_text))` and `print(len(news_date))`?
It returns 0 for me, that means that it does not returns anything

Comment: CTRL+F'd through the soup and there is no div with `class=st' nor `class=slp`. Not sure how it was working yesterday but it is possible that it was changed. Can you open the URL in browser and still find the divs with those classes?

Comment: Yeah, thats the strange part for me. When I go to 'inspect' on browser, it still has `class=st' and `class=slp`

Comment: it doesn't for me, so perhaps they are slowly rolling out a change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `user-agent` while scraping google.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

term = 'coca cola'

url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q={0}&source=lnms&tbm=nws'.format(term)

response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

snippet_text = soup.find_all('div', class_='st')
print(len(snippet_text))

news_date = soup.find_all('div', class_='slp')
print(len(news_date))
```

---

If you get SSL error maximum reach then add verify=False

```
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,verify=False)
```

Comment: Thanks , but can you explain me what have you done?
Can I apply this logic to other  websites souch as bing news, yahoo news?

Comment: If the data is not rendered by java scripts yes you can use that.However I have mentioned I have added user-agent which  a way to bypass that detection is by faking your user agent and changing it with every request you make to a website.

Comment: @taga : Not getting your last statement what are you after?

Comment: Can you maybe help me with this also?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58920075/how-to-do-sentiment-analysis-of-headlines-with-textblob-and-python

Comment: is there a way to add rotating IP address to this?
The same like you added User Agent

Comment: Sorry No idea mate

Answer (score 0):

As [KunduK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58933084/15164646) said, Google is blocking your request because the default `user-agent` from the `requests` library is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). You can fake user browser visit by adding headers to your request. [List](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/edge) of `user-agents` among other websites.

Also, you can set `timeout` to your request ([info](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts)) to stop waiting for a response after a given number of seconds. Otherwise, the script can hang indefinitely.

You **can** apply the same logic to Yahoo, Bing, Baidu, Yandex, and other search engines.

---

Code and [full example](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-News-Python-BS4-Request#main.py):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&q=coca cola&tbm=nws', headers=headers).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

for headings in soup.findAll('div', class_='dbsr'):
  title = headings.find('div', class_='JheGif nDgy9d').text
  link = headings.a['href']
  print(f'Title: {title}')
  print(f'Link: {link}')
  print()
```

Part of output:

```
Title: Fact check: Georgia is not removing Coca-Cola products from state-owned 
buildings
Link: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/factcheck/2021/04/09/fact-check-georgia-not-removing-coke-products-state-buildings/7129548002/

Title: The 'race for talent' is pushing companies like Delta and Coca-Cola to 
speak out against voting laws
Link: https://www.businessinsider.com/georgia-voting-law-merits-response-delta-coca-cola-workers-2021-4

Title: Why Coke's Earnings Could Contain Good News, One Analyst Says
Link: https://www.barrons.com/articles/cokes-stock-is-lagging-why-one-analyst-thinks-next-weeks-earnings-could-include-good-news-51618246989
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Google News Result API](https://serpapi.com/news-results) from SerpApi. Check out [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=coca%20cola&gl=us&hl=en&tbm=nws) to test.

Code to integrate:

```
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "coca cola",
  "tbm": "nws",
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for news_result in results["news_results"]:
   print(f"Title: {news_result['title']}\nLink: {news_result['link']}\n")
```

Part of output:

```
Title: Why Coke's Earnings Could Contain Good News, One Analyst Says
Link: https://www.barrons.com/articles/cokes-stock-is-lagging-why-one-analyst-thinks-next-weeks-earnings-could-include-good-news-51618246989

Title: The 'race for talent' is pushing companies like Delta and Coca-Cola to speak out against voting laws
Link: https://www.businessinsider.com/georgia-voting-law-merits-response-delta-coca-cola-workers-2021-4

Title: 2 Reasons You Shouldn't Buy Coca-Cola Now
Link: https://seekingalpha.com/article/4418712-2-reasons-you-shouldnt-buy-coca-cola-now

Title: Worrying Signs For Coca-Cola
Link: https://seekingalpha.com/article/4418630-worrying-signs-for-coca-cola
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.